# Flutter facebook login The key hash does not match any stored key hashes

Tags: facebook, flutter, facebook-login, flutter-dependencies

Im having error with hashkey, this is the error I have been receiving.

```
    I/flutter ( 8899): value: errorSERVER_ERROR: [code] 1349195 [message]: 
    The key hash does not match any stored key hashes. 
    Go to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android 
for more information. [extra]:
```

Note: I have my **HASH KEY** in my facebook developer app. I have both for **WINDOWS (DEBUG) and RELEASE** hash key. Neither, seems to work.

Ive tried only windows, release, macOS, or all at once; Nothing seems to work.

This is my code for facebook login

```
void firebaseAuthFacebook() {
    fbLogin.logIn(["email"]).then((value) {
      switch (value.status) {
        case FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn:
          print("value: loggedin");
          break;

        case FacebookLoginStatus.error:
          print("value: error"+value.errorMessage);
          break;

        case FacebookLoginStatus.cancelledByUser:
          print("value: cancelled");
          break;
      }
    }).catchError((onError) {
      print("Fblogin error: " + onError.toString());
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not works all the time!!!

Get your sha-1

Convert it into a base64
(https://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php)

paste that in your fb develop app.